# AdsConnection throws EntryPointNotFoundException on second connection but works the first time

Tags: c#, advantage-database-server

I have a piece of code that I reuse that helps me connect to an adt database and read the data.

```
using Advantage.Data.Provider;

...

protected DataTable FillTable(string tableName)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (var conn = new AdsConnection(connectionString))
    using (var adapter = new AdsDataAdapter())
    using (var cmd = new AdsCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + tableName;
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        conn.Open();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        conn.Close();
    }

    return table;
}
```

This code works perfectly the first time I go through it, but gives the following exception the second time I call it with a different table name.

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'AdsIsConnectionAlive' in DLL 'ace32.dll'.'
```

I would like an explanation.

I've tried to read up on this error, but all the possible scenario's I've found don't explain why it works the first time. They mention problems with the DLL like it being the wrong version or some incompatability with the .NET version, ...

If I change the order of the calls the code still fails on the second time, so I know the problem isn't with the name of the table or the way I call my code. The problem is probably with me not closing the connection correctly. I've tried adding more braces just to make sure that that part runs correctly and I've debugged to make sure that the first `conn.Close();` is executed correctly.

I could place all my code within this code and only use one connection that I keep open as long as I need it. That would bypass my problem, but I would like to avoid that and to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by loading an older version of ace32.dll from a newer version of the ado.net components. The AdsIsConnectionAlive was introduced in a later version of the DLL - not sure about the exact version probably 6.0 or later.

The first time the connection was made, the ado.net component knows that the connection was not alive so there was no need to call the IsAlive entry point. The second time around, since there was already a connection made to the same connection path, it would  try to reuse it by checking to see if it is still alive. I think that there is a way to disable the connection caching but do not remember the detail. A better solution would be to make sure that the advantage DLLs are matching version.

Comment: You are most likely right. I'm going to double check it, but I did have trouble with ace32.dll before. Thank you